# Is there a way to contact a specific moderator directly?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

DISCLAIMER: This isn’t about any moderator decision directly  regarding me (I don’t think I was ever subject to a direct moderator decision, or if I was, I forgot :-)

As for the title, I’d like to know if it’s possible to talk to a specific moderator directly and preferably in private. This would be a short and calm discussion, as you could expect of someone who is a “third party”.

PS the subject of said decision didn’t contact me to ask me to talk to the moderator in her/his place, of course. I would have never accepted to do something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately SE does not provide any way of contacting individual users. You can flag a question or answer with a comment for the moderator, you can use chat. So there is no such a functionality. If it is urgent, flag something and ask for a contact, as moderators can send direct e-mails to users & those can be responded, but this can be initiated only by a moderator, not by a user and should be used in special cases.

Comment: I'd also suggest flagging or a chat ping to initiate contact. Flagging will get your message to any/all moderators until it's resolved but if you have a concern about moderation this is usually appropriate (for example, if my moderation decisions are in question, I would generally seek to get other moderators involved anyway; I'm acutely aware that I am as fallible as anyone and I appreciate the advice of fellow moderators, who are a very sensible collection of people). In some cases issues might reasonably be raised on meta, particularly if it's a question of policy or how it's applied.

Comment: Moderators can set up a private chat room to talk to specified users. I think "private" there means only those users, plus site moderators, plus community managers can enter it.

Comment: @Tim yes, I know SE doesn't allow to contact individual users, but I thought that was only for "common" users, not for moderators. The issue is definitely not so serious that I would consider it a special case, so if direct email are reserved for special action (I guess because they're sent from the moderator's personal email, so they violate her/his anonimity), then it's not the appropriate tool for my problem.

Comment: @Glen_b ok, I guess I'll either flag the message or ping the involved moderator in chat. The point is, I didn't want to discuss the matter in public (it's nothing serious! Just a little bit private), so I was wondering if there was any other way, but I don't think there is. I'll guess I'll flag. Is there a way to see the list of current moderators on Cross Validated?

Comment: @Scortchi ah, this is very interesting: a private chat would be the **perfect** tool for my use case. However, since from the current discussion I'm getting the feeling that the preferred way to deal with these things is flagging, I'll just flag the message.

Comment: here goes nothing: I flagged the question. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: I believe others can *see* the content of a private chat room, they just can't say anything. I could be wrong, but I believe that to be the case.

Comment: Another way to communicate with anyone in a somewhat clandestine manner is to find an old, little viewed post by them & leave them a comment. Afterwards, the comments can be deleted.

Comment: @gung: When you create a room, you're given the options 'Public', 'Gallery', & 'Private': it's the galleries that anyone can enter though only only specified users can speak.

Comment: @DeltaIV Do you refer to one of the only two moderators that are unidentifiable via a quick look on their stack-exchange profiles?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings: Don't you mean "five" (two are identifiable)?

Comment: @Scortchi you are right it was less. I was wrong about one.  It is four in total. One has his username similar to his first and last name (and also links to his personal website), one has has his username similar to his first letter and last name (and used to have a link somewhere to his consultancy company), one has a link to his github page, one has a link to his twitter page,